# Update discord-buttons on InteractionCreate

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

In Discord MessageButtons, MessageActionRow

I'm having a **MessageActionRow()** running into a message embed, added buttons **addComponents** to that message, on createInteraction when a "PauseButton" is clicked, the button replaces with another button called "ResumeButton", same same.

```
const PauseButton = new MessageButton()
.setCustomId('PauseButton')
.setLabel('Pause')
.setStyle('SUCCESS')
.setEmoji('⏸️');

const ResumeButton = new MessageButton()
.setCustomId('ResumeButton')
.setLabel('Resume')
.setStyle('SUCCESS')
.setEmoji('▶️');

//SkipButton, StopButton

const Buttons = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(PauseButton, SkipButton, StopButton);
const ResumeButtons = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(ResumeButton, SkipButton, StopButton);

const sendMessage = await QueueChannel.send({ embeds: [sendMessageEmbed], components: [Buttons] });

this.client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
if (!interaction.isButton()) return;
// Pause
if (interaction.customId === "PauseButton") {
    player.pause(true);
    const int = await interaction.deferUpdate({
      fetchReply: true,
    });
    if (!int) return smt
    await int.edit({
      components: [ResumeButtons],
    });
    if(int.deleted) {
      interaction.channel.send()
    }
    }
// Resume
if (interaction.customId === "ResumeButton") {
    player.pause(false);
    const int = await interaction.deferUpdate({
      fetchReply: true,
    });
    if (!int) return smt
    await int.edit({
      components: [Buttons],
    });
    if(int.deleted) {
      interaction.channel.send()
    }
}
```

This returns the error `DiscordAPIError: Unknown interaction` ln line 23:13 `await interaction.deferUpdate` on await.

Basically, the code does the job (it works fully functional) except:
On the **First run**, everything works fine,
On the **Second run**, when I click any button, an error returns "Unknown interaction"
and the reason is that the the code is running twice, I knew when I added `console.log("PauseButton")` on the interact, the log returned twice to console `PauseButton PauseButton` instead of once.

Meaning there are 2 listeners for the ineractionCreate or something? Do I need to remove any interaction when the message is removed?

I need help please, anything is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The process was duplicating because I had an `interactionCreate.js` in that project. I felt so confused because there was so many files, code has no issues, my apologize.